# Titanium Appcelerator - Save GPS track

Tags: android, gps, appcelerator, tracking, appcelerator-titanium

I'd like to save a GPS track in an app made with Titanium (Android for the moment), but I don't know how to do it.

My goal would be to track the position of the user every 5 seconds and save it in the phone (in a JSON file, I think, would be the better solution). I want it to function both in background, and if the phone has no network.
And once the phone has network, I want to synchronize the file to the server.

Is it possible ?

For the moment, I just put a basic function (from appcelerator doc) with a setInterval ... but the position is always the same, even if I'm moving.

Here is my code :

```
function save(){
    setInterval(function(){
        if (Ti.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled) {
            Titanium.Geolocation.purpose = 'Get Current Location';
            Titanium.Geolocation.distanceFilter = 1 ;
            Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
                if (e.error) {
                    Ti.API.error('Error: ' + e.error);
                } else {
                    Ti.API.info(e.coords.altitude);
                    Ti.API.info(e.coords.heading);
                    Ti.API.info(e.coords.latitude);
                    Ti.API.info(e.coords.longitude);
                    Ti.API.info(e.coords.speed);

                    alert('LAT : '+e.coords.latitude+' LONG : '+e.coords.longitude+' SPEED : '+e.coords.speed+' ALT : '+e.coords.altitude);
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert('Please enable location services');
        }

    }, 5000);
}

save_button.addEventListener('click', function(){

    save();

});
```

I don't really know how to do that properly. If some people can help me ... :)

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Can you post the code snippet responsible for getting the geolocation?

Comment: Save the GPS positions in a SQLite database (Ti.Database) instead of a JSON file. And much more important: use a custom module to track significant changes of the GPS location. The provided geolocation module (Ti.Geolocation) is on Android quite slow and inaccurate.

Comment: @Soumya I've added my code snippet :)

Comment: @danny005, So, one 'INSERT', every 5 seconds ? Can you tell me why it is better ? And can you give me a name of module ? :)

Thanks !

Comment: yes, one insert every 5seconds. Performance-wise much better than a txt file if you have a lot of records. I have a custom geolocation module (based on FusedLocationProviderApi like Google Maps does) but it's not open-source or for free.

Comment: Your code snippet is btw not uptodate. See an example here (and with a discussion about location updates): https://archive.appcelerator.com/topic/846/android-geolocation-locationprovider-locationrule-have-no-effect-whatsoever

Comment: Why not register for the location event. This will get fired when there is a change in the location? Can you try this and see if the movement is getting generated. Also confirm the accuracy which has been set. It will factor in here.

Comment: Check this proyect: https://github.com/FokkeZB/Tracker =)

Comment: It seems ... difficult :D
But I'm going to try. Thank you for your answers ! :)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to track gps position it's be better if you set an eventListener 
`Ti.Geolocation.addEventListener('location', function(e){
    //same response returned by Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
});`

the sensitivity of the listener can be adjust like this

```
Ti.Geolocation.Android.manualMode = true;

function androidProviderConfig(provider) {
    var providerGps = Ti.Geolocation.Android.createLocationProvider({
        name : provider,
        minUpdateDistance : 100,
        //minUpdateTime: 60
    });
    Ti.Geolocation.Android.addLocationProvider(providerGps);
    var gpsRule = Ti.Geolocation.Android.createLocationRule({
        provider : provider,
        accuracy : 50,
        maxAge : 20 * 60 * 1000, // 1h
        minAge : 10 * 1000 // 10 seconde
    });
    Ti.Geolocation.Android.addLocationRule(gpsRule);
}

//androidProviderConfig(Ti.Geolocation.PROVIDER_NETWORK);
//or
androidProviderConfig(Ti.Geolocation.PROVIDER_GPS);
Ti.Geolocation.addEventListener('location', function(e){/*your callback*/});
```